# Create a hierarchy from an array that has hierarchy information in an attribute that is string with separator ">"

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, hierarchy, traversal

let's say I have an array of objects as below, this array has a list of objects which has a key and document count, the key has hierarchical information as a string separated by ">", the start of the attribute is parent, and then its child and so on.

```
[
    {
      key: 'sport',
      doc_count: 2
    },
    {
      key: 'sport>competition',
      doc_count: 2
    },
    {
      key: 'sport>competition>cricket',
      doc_count: 1
    },
    {
      key: 'sport>competition>football',
      doc_count: 1
    },
    {
      key: 'movies',
      doc_count: 1
    }
    {
      key: 'movies>english',
      doc_count: 1
    }
]
```

Can any one suggest me the quickest method to convert this array to this hierarchical data(See Below) in javascript.

```
[
  {
    label: 'sport',
    parent: null,
    doc_count: 2,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'competition',
        parent: 'sport',
        doc_count: 2,
        children: [
          {
            label: 'cricket',
            parent: 'competition',
            doc_count: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            label: 'football',
            parent: 'competition',
            doc_count: 1,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'movies',
    parent: null,
    doc_count: 1,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'english',
        parent: 'movies',
        doc_count: 1,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

Comment: what have you tried ? You can make use of `recursive approach` to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do it for you (not out of malice, just because I'm not 100% sure I understand the question correctly), 
but I'll hopefully give you a big point in the right direction.

The problem has something to do with recursion. If you are not aware recursion look like this:

```
function walk(items){
  items.forEach(items => {
    if(item.hasChildrenOrSomething){
      // notice the function calls itself:
      walk(item.children);
    }

    // Do something with item
  });
}

walk(tree);
```

Here is a way to classify them in a tree structure, later on you can modify the data in it. This is just a step towards your solution.

I'm `reducing` the data here and calling a recursive function `resolveData` by passing `accumulator` and `splitted key`.
You can understand it better from the code:

```js
var data = [{ key: 'sport', doc_count: 2 }, { key: 'sport>competition', doc_count: 2 }, { key: 'sport>competition>cricket', doc_count: 1 }, { key: 'sport>competition>football', doc_count: 1 }, { key: 'movies', doc_count: 1 }, { key: 'movies>english', doc_count: 1 }];

let resolveData = (acc, keyArray) => {
   if (keyArray.length > 1) {
    getIndex = acc.findIndex(val => val.key == keyArray[0]);
    acc[getIndex].children = acc[getIndex].children || [];
    isPresent = acc[getIndex].children.find(val => val.key == keyArray[1]);
    if (!isPresent) acc[getIndex].children = [...acc[getIndex].children, { key: keyArray[1], children: [] }];
    keyArray.shift();
    resolveData(acc[getIndex].children, keyArray); // here we are performing recursion
}
  return acc;
};

var tree = data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  keys = elem.key.split('>');
  if (keys.length == 1) {
      acc.push(elem); // pushing parent element here
    } else {
      var result = resolveData(acc, keys);
      getAccIndex = acc.findIndex((value) => value.key == result[0].key);
      acc[getAccIndex] = result[0];
    }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(tree);
```

I hope this will lead you to further direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this method,

````
function buildHierarchy(data) {

    const categories = data.map((value) => {
      const categoryKeys = value.key.split('>');
      return {
        label: categoryKeys[categoryKeys.length - 1],
        parent: (categoryKeys.length > 1) ? categoryKeys[categoryKeys.length - 2] : null,
        doc_count: value.doc_count
      };
    });

    // Create list for top-level node(s)
    const list = [];
    // Cache for found parent index
    const categoryMap = {};

    categories.forEach((topic: Topic) => {
      // No parentId means top level
      if (!topic.parent) {
        return list.push(topic);
      }
      // Insert node as child of parent in flat array
      let parent = categoryMap[topic.parent];
      if (typeof parent !== 'string') {
        parent = categories.findIndex((el: Topic) => el.label === topic.parent);
        categoryMap[topic.parent] = parent;
      }

      if (!categories[parent].children) {
        return categories[parent].children = [topic];
      }

      categories[parent].children.push(topic);
    });

    return list;
  }```
````